# Type (in a type hint) that can be set like a parameter

Tags: python, python-typing

I have several classes doing the same logic and sharing majority of code. Just the type of data they can process differs. I'd like to ask how to write type hints in a case like shown below.

```
# incorrect code
class Foo:
    def add_one(self, item: DataType) -> None:
        ...
    def get_all(self) -> list[DataType]:
        ...

DataType=int
class IntFoo(Foo):
    pass

DataType=str
class StringFoo(Foo):
    pass
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics, https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html

Comment: @Brian61354270 Thanks, "generic classes" is what I was looking for.